# I M GETTING 404 ERROR EVERYTIME I RUN THIS CODE

Tags: http-status-code-404

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

app.route('/game', methods=['GET'])
def attendance():

    return "hello"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this for a minimal flask application

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

Your example looks something like this:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/game')
def attendance():
    return 'hello'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

run the app.py (local) and open in browser as:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/game
```